# ruby array batch size character limit

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to debug an issue from copied code and have searched now three days but can't get it working as intended.

I need to iterate through an array but stick to a character limit. So I group them. Issue is now that the code below sometimes duplicates values.

I'm new to ruby and work on reused [code](https://gist.github.com/chezou/9919f5065cbc52f8d0349d3084ac3616). So had to learn quite a bit.

Array that is produced is :

```
[" abc def ghi", "klm klm nop qrs", "tuv tuv wxy z"]
```

It should be:

```
[" abc def ghi", "klm nop qrs", "tuv wxy z"]
```

---

```
module TextFetcher
  def self.fetch_text_from()

  node_texts = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "klm", "nop", "qrs", "tuv", "wxy", "z"]
  combined_texts = []
  tmp_string = ""

  node_texts.each do |text|
    #puts text.size

  if tmp_string.size + text.size > 14
    combined_texts << tmp_string
    tmp_string = text
  end
  tmp_string << " #{text}"
  end
  #puts text
  combined_texts << tmp_string
  p combined_texts
  end
end

input_texts = TextFetcher.fetch_text_from()

input_texts.each.with_index do |text, i|

    #puts "\n"
    #puts text

end
```

Comment: Please state **the problem** clearly. In Layman’s terms, like “I have that and I need that, and I yielded that.”

Comment: Need to get rid of the duplicate entries that are produced. See second array item: It has "klm klm nop qrs" but it should have only "klm nop qrs" . so klm got duplicated. –

Answer (score 0):

**NB** I am answering the exact question stated.

> Need to get rid of the duplicate entries that are produced.

```
input = [" abc def ghi", "klm klm nop qrs", "tuv tuv wxy z"]
input.map { |e| e.split(' ').reject(&:empty?).uniq.join(' ') }
#⇒ [
#  [0] "abc def ghi",
#  [1] "klm nop qrs",
#  [2] "tuv wxy z"
# ]
```

Comment: I think he wants to avoid having the duplicates in the first place.

Comment: @cobaltsoda I do not care what he wants. I answer the question stated. This is neither code review for free service nor a fortunetellers party.

Comment: Haha fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line `tmp_string = text` and replacing it with `tmp_string = ""` will stop duplicates from being added.

**Edit:** if you want the spaces removed from the start of each string, replace the code in your `node_texts.each do |text|` block with:

```
#puts text.size
if tmp_string.size + text.size > 14
  combined_texts << tmp_string
  tmp_string = text
else
  tmp_string << " #{text}"
end
```